# Force rewrite of Gnome-Do summon binding on login because keeps being set to disabled

Tags: 12.04, unity, gnome, gnome-do

I was wondering where the gnome-do binding was stored for summon do. I want to rewrite this on login because it keeps getting overwritten when I have it stored as space to disabled.

Where is this setting stored and how do I go about rewriting it?

Answer (score 1):

The keybindings are stored in GConf - `/apps/gnome-do/preferences/Do/Platform/Common/AbstractKeyBindingService/`.

Although, since you've tagged this GNOME3, most likely your problem is that GNOME Shell claims the <kbd>Super</kbd> key, so Do can't bind to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

The next version of Do will notify you when this is the case so you can change your keybinding to something that will work.

Comment: I've debuged a little and the gconf values are not changed but still in the menu it labels the summon-do as disabled. I have set the summon dash as <super><shift> so shouldn't conflict but I still think it is disabling it for some reason. Can I somehow force it to reload the gconf settings so it isn't disabled?

Comment: I can bind to Super+Space without trouble, but when I restart my computer, the binding is gone.

Comment: I have the exact same problem as user802500.

Comment: A little clarification. When I restart my computer and log in the key-binding to summon Gnome-do is set correctly. But if i log out and back in again the key-biding is disabled.