# Cannot summon Gnome-Do

Tags: gnome, awesome, gnome-do

I use awesomewm and I have installed gnome-do. When I start it, I see this:

```
[SystemService] Could not initialize dbus: Unable to open the session message bus.
(Do:3128): Wnck-CRITICAL **: wnck_set_client_type got called multiple times.
(Do:3128): libdo-WARNING **: Binding '<Super>space' failed!
```

It is clear, it cannot map space combination, because awesomewm uses this one. However, I can see gnome-do in my processes. How I can summon it? Some people tell me that I should see the gnome-do welcome window, but I don't.

I tried what is written in this post (http://askubuntu.com/questions/157195/force-rewrite-of-gnome-do-summon-binding-on-login-because-keeps-being-set-to-dis). But it does not work, because every time I restart gnome-do, my binding written by hands disappears.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution:

```
dbus-launch gnome-do
```

However, I don't know why I need to start gnome-do like this. Others start it normally. If you have a solution how to configure dbus to avoid dbus-launch, please, live a comment.

Comment: I recommend asking a separate question about this new, more specific problem.

Comment: Do you know more these days? I'm curious!

Comment: No. If it is relevant, I am using cairo-dock with <Super> + ` hotkey, to launch applications, guake and multiple workspaces.

Answer (score 1):

Running `gnome-do` again from the run dialog (if it is already running) will summon it. At that point you will be able to change the keyboard combination in preferences > keyboard.

Comment: I wrote in my post that I don't see the gnome-do window, when I start it.